# NSMutableArray contains nil pointer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

I'm using `-insertObject:atIndex:` to add some instances of a custom class called `DecryptedItem` to a `NSMutableArray`. `DecryptedItem` implements its own `-hash` and `-isEqual:` methods, though as far as I know this is not relevant when the objects are added to a array.

After inserting an object at index 0, another one also at index 0 and an additional one at 1 I get the following very wierd behavior: The array shows up as an array of 3 elements in the debug window, and calling `-description` on the array shows that it contains three different objects. However, looking at the array in the debugger shows that one object is nil! I noticed this when I was searching for a particular object using `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`, which returned `NSNotFound`.

[image: Strange NSMutableArray behavior]

Comment: How you are using storing the data in the NSMutableArray? Code ?

Comment: inserting nil should crash the app during insert unless you are fetching this data from a method which returns NSNull object when the object is nil. e.g. object parsed from a json string.

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: This is probably just the debugger getting confused somehow. If the description method shows all three objects, they're all in there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the array was not sorted correctly and therefore `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` did not work properly. Everything seems fine now. Guess it actually was just the debugger being quirky.